# Can we modify the UIViewController property in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiinterfaceorientation

iOS has a pre declared property as per below:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation;
```

Can I modify it to `@property(nonatomic) UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation;` for my project and then assign different values to "`interfaceOrientation`" variable in different controller methods of my class?

Should it create a problem if I modify the existing property?

Also, while googling, I somewhere read that if a @property(nonatomic) is not declared with "readonly" keyword, then its read-write by default. Is this rule applicable only for the properties defined by the developer and not for the pre-defined properties?

Answer (score 1):

No, if it's readonly then there is a reason. To provide different behavior you should subclass the `UIViewController` and override the specified methods [[1]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation) [[2]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations):

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

Comment: Also, while googling, I somewhere read that if a @property(nonatomic) is not declared with "readonly" keyword, then its read-write by default. Is this rule applicable only for the properties defined by the developer and not for the pre-defined properties?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that's not possible. As Cocoa Touch is build based on design patterns (in our case Open Close Principle, see more at http://www.oodesign.com/open-close-principle.html), that would violate one of them. You can add more functions/features, but cannot modify the existing ones. Hope that helps

Comment: Also, while googling, I somewhere read that if a @property(nonatomic) is not declared with "readonly" keyword, then its read-write by default. Is this rule applicable only for the properties defined by the developer and not for the pre-defined properties?

Comment: I guess this rule is the same in all cases. It's a language rule, and the developers of the iOS SDK use the same language - Objective-C, as all of us. Hope that makes sense